# Riemann integration on product of functions

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

This is just a curious thought of mine.

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are real continuous functions on closed interval $[a,b]$ and $\int_{a}^{b} f = 0$, does that therefore imply that $\int_{a}^{b}  fg=0$? If so could someone please construct a proof for me please?

If I remove the condition that both functions are continuous, then will this affect the conclusion?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: It doesn't. $\int_0^{2\pi} \sin x dx = 0$ but $\int_0^{2\pi} \sin^2 x dx > 0$. The counterexample generalizes to any interval $[a, b]$ by some transformation of sine.

Comment: @Jakobian Or to $f=g$.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path yes, for any continuous $f\not \equiv 0$

Comment: In fact, $<f, g> = \int_a^b fg$ introduces a scalar product in the space of continuous functions defined on $[a, b]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody can prove it, since it is false. Take $a=-1$, $b=1$, and $f(x)=g(x)=x$, for instance. The $\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx=0$, but $\int_a^bf(x)g(x)\,\mathrm dx=\frac23$.

Comment: Ahh yes, I should of noticed that. Hmm If I say f is non-negative and continuous then I guess it will be true then?

Comment: Yes, because then $f$ must be the null function.

Answer (score 1):

Answer when you add the condition that $f$ is non-negative and continuous (following your comment to the previous answer): in this case let us show that $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ which makes it obvious that $\int fg=0$. Suppose, if possible, $f(x) \neq 0$ for s0me $x$. By continuity there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|f(y)-f(x)| <\frac {f(x)} 2$ for $|y-x| <\delta$. Now $f(y) >f(x)-\frac {f(x)} 2=\frac {f(x)} 2$ for $y \in (x-\delta,x+\delta)$. Hence $\int_a^{b} f(y)\, dy \geq \int_{x-\delta}^{x+\delta} f(y)\, dy > 2\delta\frac {f(x)} 2 >0$ contradicting the hypothesis. Hence $f \equiv 0$.